# Packstack installation with no root user?

Tags: centos, openstack

Is there any way to change the SSH user during the installation (image at the end for clarification)? I do not have access for the root user, but I have another user with root permits. Using the ~/ssh/config file seems to have no effect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO8VJ.png (image description)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the SSH daemon is being established, it means that you are able to connect with the user defined during the installation.

Still, if you want to connect as root you have to change its pass:

```
sudo su -
passwd
```

Then modify vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change settings to:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

This is just an example of course.

Comment: Well, the problem is during the installation (as shown in the image) not after. The installation tries to connect using the root user, but I do not have the password so I'm trying to change the user during the installation proccess.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right, never seen such installation step though. May be it's worth providing some more details about that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo -i` then 
generate rsa keys for root and append public key to authorized_keys

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

This worked for me to solve a similar problem while trying to run packstack